# Namespace Error on MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, namespaces, compiler-errors, monodevelop, xamarin.android

I have been getting the following error.
1 :the type or namespace name' CountDownTime' does not exist in the namespace 'System'(are you missing an assembly reference)
2 : the type or namespace naem 'Runtime' does not exist in the namespace Andriod.OS( are you missing an assembly reference)

I would like the code to generate 10 subtraction question, present the answer, and then give the time spent on the test.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.CountDownTimer;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS.Runtime;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android;

namespace Jagtutor
{
    public class Subtraction : View
    {
        public Subtraction (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base (context, attrs)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        public Subtraction (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
            base (context, attrs, defStyle)
        {
            Initialize ();
        }

        private void Initialize ()
        {
            int correctCount;
            int count = 0;
            long startTime = CountDownTimer(0);

            while (count < 10)
            {
                // Generate two random single-digit numbers
                srand(CountDownTimer(0));
                int number1 = Random() % 10;
                int number2 = Random() % 10;

                // if number1 < number, swap number1 with number2
                if (number1 < number2)
                {
                    int temp = number1;
                    number1 = number2;
                    number2 = temp; 

                    // PROMPT THE STUDENT TO ANSWER " WHAT IS NUMBERE1 - NUMBER2?"
                    Console.WriteLine("WHAT IS ")(number1);" - "(number2)("?");

                    // Grade the answer and display the result
                    if (number1 - number2 == answer){
                        Console.Write("You are correct!");
                        correctCount++;
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is wrong");
                    Console.WriteLine(number1);"-"(number2); " should be" (number1 - number2);

                    // increase the count 
                    count++;
                }
                long endTime = CountDownTimer(0);
                long testTime = endTime - startTime; 

                Console.Write(" Correct count is ")(correctCount);" Test time is" (testTime)("seconds");
                return 0;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please learn to format your code here on Stack Overflow for your next questions. The code formatter here doesn't like tabs, so preferably use only spaces. When you have pasted the code into the edit box, select the whole code and press `Ctrl+K` or click the `{}` icon above the edit box.

Answer (score 1):

The C# [using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) is used with *namespaces*, not *types*. There is no `System.CountDownTimer` namespace, hence the error.

For that matter, there isn't a `System.CountDownTimer` type either; it's [Android.OS.CountDownTimer](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.OS.CountDownTimer), so you'd need:

```
using Android.OS;
```

Similarly, there is no `Android.OS.Runtime` namespace, so `using Android.OS.Runtime;` will also generate a compile-time error; remove it.

Answer (score 0):

With the other ones, add:

`using Android.OS;`